# c#-is it possible to edit an item in a text file using the update in listview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listview

I'm having a hard time elaborating my question. But I created a registration form in visual studio that gets the important details of a student. Clicking the register button will save the inputs in a text file and adding all the information in a listview. I want to know if it is possible to update an item in the text file using only the listview(update).

For example, I already saved 1 line of student information, now another student saves information. I want to go back to the previous line of details and I want to edit it, without opening the text file, using the listview only.

Comment: The only way to achieve this is if you keep a Memory Object what has all the lines in a list, and every change you do to a line, update the entry in the list. When you want to save the content, concatenate all the entries from the list, in a single block of text, and overwrite it to the file.

I do not know if there is a way to keep an active pointer to a file to be able to update single lines of text.

Why aren`t you using a database for this, instead of files?

Comment: Hey Lupu, thank you for answering. My employer asked me to save the information on a text file without using a database. Also, I'm new to this language so I'm not that experienced yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is NO. There is a clear separation of responsibilities. The `Listview` is responsible for the display of data on the GUI. Your textfile (and the object to read and write the file) is responsible for the storage. Now you could link the update function to the process of the file reading and writing operation, be without effort from your side the two remain separate entities with separate responsibilities (which is actually good, because you know who does what).

> I want to go back to the previous line of details and I want to edit it without opening the text file

You cannot change a file without opening it. It is like trying to take out a cookie without opening the box :) you need to reach inside, so the box has to be openend.

Comment: Thank you Mong Zhu for answering my question. I finally understand.

Comment: @ElChapo you are welcome. You could also take the Listview as the representation of your file. Load the entire file into the listview, then every time the user changes something in the listview overwrite the entire file and write the entire content of the listview into the file. This way is not the cheapest from the point of resources but it is the simplest to ensure a coherence between data storage and the display of it.